# active admin strong parameters failing

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to create a record in active admin. My activeadmin is set up with this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyObject do
   permit_params :all_my_params, :client_id
end
```

The form should be submitting the params as such:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WnStZr//M1rBDSwNWSrZs2rvCmcpji/MKaLywxuf9oG0Ef3b1uojy5jszs3yHEYmpvjt+qtJrmi3jz3KKJgUCQ==", "MyObject"=>{"client_id"=>"1", "all_my_params"=>"something here"}, "commit"=>"Create My Object"}
```

However, the form submits with an extra client_id outside of the MyObject hash like so:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WnStZr//M1rBDSwNWSrZs2rvCmcpji/MKaLywxuf9oG0Ef3b1uojy5jszs3yHEYmpvjt+qtJrmi3jz3KKJgUCQ==", "MyObject"=>{"client_id"=>"1", "all_my_params"=>"something here"}, "commit"=>"Create My Object", "client_id"=>"1"}
```

(notice the extra client_id)
This gives me an error:

> unpermitted parameter: client_id

because it is not expected outside my MyObject hash. 
How can I fix this? I've been stuck on this for days!

```
My relevant routes: batch_action_admin_client_wedding_cakes POST       /admin/clients/:client_id/wedding_cakes/batch_action(.:format)             admin/wedding_cakes#batch_action
          admin_client_wedding_cakes GET        /admin/clients/:client_id/wedding_cakes(.:format)                          admin/wedding_cakes#index
                                     POST       /admin/clients/:client_id/wedding_cakes(.:format)                          admin/wedding_cakes#create
       new_admin_client_wedding_cake GET        /admin/clients/:client_id/wedding_cakes/new(.:format)                      admin/wedding_cakes#new
      edit_admin_client_wedding_cake GET        /admin/clients/:client_id/wedding_cakes/:id/edit(.:format)                 admin/wedding_cakes#edit
           admin_client_wedding_cake GET        /admin/clients/:client_id/wedding_cakes/:id(.:format)                      admin/wedding_cakes#show
```

where wedding_cake = MyObject in my previous code.

In essence, the client_id that is parsed from the url automatically which would normally be accepted in a rails controller is not getting accepted in activeadmin and I have no way of making it permitted since I can only permit things that are inside the wedding cakes hash in my params.

Comment: Possibly you have a hidden field with that client id. Could you add a rendered html form to you question?

Comment: There is. I added it, but is added as name="MyObject[client_id]" Because I do need that parameter. The other client_id is the id that is parsed from the url since I am working with nested resources. I.E /client/1/MyObject parses client_id as 1 automatically and adds it to the params, but is not accepted for some reason.

Comment: That might be coming from your routes? Do `rake routes` and see if it has `:client_id` param for that active admin page. It is a long shot, but still. Also, please add your rendered HTML form.

Comment: The rendered html is several hundred lines long, so I think it's best not to post it here, but I checked, there is nothing submitting client_id outside of MyObject (in reality wedding_cake if you are looking at my routes). Here is the form html: <form novalidate="novalidate" class="formtastic wedding_cake" id="new_wedding_cake" action="/admin/clients/1/wedding_cakes" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden">

Comment: As suspected, your `:client_id` is coming from your routes.

Comment: Exactly, and in a normal controller that is accepted just fine, but in activeadmin it rejects that parameter because I cannot permit parameters outside of wedding_cake

Comment: Did you try adding accecpts_nested_attributes for :client to the wedding cake model?

Comment: that doesn't seam to make a difference, still getting the same error

Comment: Is ActiveAdmin giving you that error or is it Rails itself? You might need to (somehow, somewhere) permit the param in rails. Like you said, "[you] can only permit things that are inside the wedding cakes hash in my params" but that is _within_ ActiveAdmin. So look outside of ActiveAdmin. I hope that helps. I haven't worked with ActiveAdmin but I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried various things in my regular controller to no avail. I think the problem is in activeadmin's default controllers. I just created custom collection_action controllers in activeadmin that take the place of the default controllers, and I no longer have the problem. It would be nice to know how to fix this without overriding the default controllers though!